# PHP If else solution

Tags: php, if-statement, pi

Can it works with this if else or can't i write it so? I need help with the if and else Problem. So can i write if² than if³ and than else³ and else².

```
<?php
if (empty($_POST['blue'])) {
    echo '<img src="images/error.png">';
}else {
    if($_POST['blue']<256 && $_POST['blue']>=0){
        echo $_POST['blue'];
        if($_POST['blue']>0){
            echo shell_exec("sudo python3 var/www/switcher.py -p 5 h");
        }else {
            echo shell_exec("sudo python3 var/www/switcher.py -p 5 l");
        }
    } else {
        echo '<img src="images/error.png">';
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: hi, the best way is to use switch/case approach

Comment: Can you show me that. Thats my first PHP programming. :/ 
So you can show who you mean it

Comment: i don't understand your question ?

Comment: My Question is can i write if than if and than else and thane the else of the first if argument

Comment: What do you mean by `if³` ?

Answer (score 0):

Without inner if else condition, you can also write in this way:

```
<?php
if($_POST['blue']<256 && $_POST['blue']>0){ 
    echo shell_exec("sudo python3 var/www/switcher.py -p 5 h");
}
else if($_POST['blue']<256 && $_POST['blue']==0){
    echo shell_exec("sudo python3 var/www/switcher.py -p 5 l");
}
else{
    echo '<img src="images/error.png">';
}
?>
```